# ldap nested group membership filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I tried using LDAP matching rule but i am not able to retrieve search entries usind LDAP matching rule filter.

This is how i am sending the filter:
filter      `(&(objectclass=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=)(cn=gasaxena))`

I dumped the filter in pcap received on ldap server as well and this is how it looks like:
filter: `(&(&(objectclass=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=[NULL]))(cn=gasaxena))`

Can someone point out, if i have missed out anything? The server is AD

Answer (score 5):

You should perform the search against the group similar to:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=John Smith,DC=MyDomain,DC=NET)
```

Not memberOf on the user.

-jim

Comment: THANKS JIM,
with your help, i was able to retrieve multiple search entries corresponding to multiple nested groups to which user was part of. However, after at the end of the search i am also seeing "ldapsearchresref" as part of this nested filter search. Is this expected? Will it be a valid assumption ldapsearchresref as a indicator of end of my search result?

Answer (score 4):

To understand Active-Directory filters, just have a look to [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To find all the groups that "user1" is a member of :

In your search, set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=dom,dc=fr)

Set the scope to subtree

Use the following filter : `(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)`

**Example** with LDIFDE.EXE (native command line AD search on windows) :

```
ldifde -f t.txt -d "DC=dom,DC=fr" -r "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=jblanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr)"
```

This find all the groups jpblanc is member of.

Comment: Hi, 
I am stuck here and could use a bit of help from experts.
My user is "SPR" and it is located under dc=aaaldap,dc=com
Now the filter i am trying to send is
Filter: (&(objectclass=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=gasaxena,dc=aaaldap,dc=com))

Comment: Read my answer, try with member and not memberof

Comment: Thannks JPBlanc. i somehow managed to miss difference between member and memberOf in my filter. Thanks for your help. I corrected that and it is now working. However, i am observing ldapsearchresref message at the end of multiple search entries i am getting based on nested-user. So, will it be a valid assumption to assume that for nested group filter, ldapsearchresref will the last message indicating end of search entry result

Comment: I've been trying to use the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` for days but never success. My RODC is just returning gargabe. I've tried using `member` instead of `memberof` and even filtering to keep only `group` objects but still the command returns a few hundred people of type `person`. Doesn't make any sense. I give up this garbage and I'll do the recursive search manually. LDAP is so frustrating

Answer (score 2):

You must use the full distinguished name of your group when using **memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=** in my case **CN=MyGroup,OU=User,OU=Groups,OU=Security,DC=domain,DC=com** was the whole distinguished name

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MyGroup,OU=User,OU=Groups,OU=Security,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

you can get the distinguished name of you group by running the following code and putting in this filter **(&(objectClass=group)(name=MyGroup))**

```
    Imports System.DirectoryServices

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim run As Boolean = True
            Dim Filter As String
            While run
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Filter:")
                Filter = Console.ReadLine()
                If Filter = "exit" Then
                    run = False
                Else
                    checkFilter(Filter)
                End If
            End While
        End Sub

        Function checkFilter(Filter As String) As Boolean
            Dim search As New DirectorySearcher("LDAP://dc=Domain,dc=com")
            Try
                search.Filter = Filter
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
                search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
                Dim results As SearchResultCollection = search.FindAll()
                If results Is Nothing Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing")
                    Return False
                Else
                    If results.Count() = 0 Then
                        Console.WriteLine("non found")
                    End If
                    Dim result As SearchResult
                    For Each result In results
                        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("name")(0).ToString())
                        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0).ToString())
                        'For Each prop In result.Properties("members")
                        '    Console.WriteLine(prop.ToString())
                        'Next
                    Next
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Users Found", results.Count()))
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
            Return True
        End Function
    End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

This component is incorrect: `(&(objectclass=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=)(cn=gasaxena))`.

Perhaps you meant:

`(&(objectclass=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=gasaxena,<superior-portion-of-distinguished-name-here>))`

Comment: Thanks Terry. But i am kind of new to LDAP and doesn't understand this filters concept pretty well. Can you please help me in interpreting the two syntaxes and how does the two differ with respect to server interpretation.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: [ad search filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi,
I tried by changing the filter but still not able to retrieve any search entries. I dumped the filter as well:
filter      (&(objectclass=*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=gasaxena))
Any pointers on what i may be missing? Is there any knob which we need to turn on AD server to make this search query work?